# A property grid in jQuery

Tags: jquery, grid, propertygrid

I want to create a property grid like this: [Ext JS Property Grid demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/property.html)

However I don't want to use extjs, and am using jQuery instead. What plugin would most easily enable to me create a propertygrid?

jqGrid is the only one that I know of right now.
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

I am not interested in loading data from XML file or database, I should be able to set data from objects on the page.

**Edit:** I just realized that there is another plugin with the same name:
http://jqframework.com/jqgrid/

Ohh namespacing fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jqGrid has support for creating a grid from local JavaScript objects or from a table tag embedded in the page (via [`tableToGrid`](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2h30t8wte.htm)).

Here are the [general docs for jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). The array info is under Loading Data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you think jqGrid is the best solution? What the its pros and cons vs other plugins?

Comment: I've only used jqGrid for a short time. I've sometimes had problems figuring out how to get it to solve my problem (the docs aren't written the way I think, I guess), but it's been very slick once I figure out a given feature, and the integration with jQuery UI themes is nice. The biggest pro I've found is that it provides most of the features I want, e.g., inline editing and progressive enhancement. Most of the others I looked at only had one or the other.

Answer (score 18):

ive created a jquery property grid on this site

http://www.cssedit.co.uk/

heres the js http://www.cssedit.co.uk/exemples/scripts/PropertyGrid.js , have a look at  /exemples/SCRIPTS/STYLER.JS for how i use the javascript propertygrid

col